# PDO PostgreSQL binding error

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I found that when I'm trying to run update query with params, I'm getting error

> inconsistent types deduced for parameter

Maybe that's because the type of target field (*character varying*), everything works fine with *text* column type. But I don't want to change column type only because of this. Then I was told that I should pass params directly (using bindValue or bindParam, determining the type of each value) instead of sending params array to *execute* method.

But when I do so I'm getting error

> ERROR:  bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement
>   "pdo_stmt_00000001" requires 1

The test code is

```
$Stmt = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE test_field=:test_field");
$Stmt->bindValue(':test_field', 'test', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$Stmt->execute();
var_dump($DB->errorInfo());
```

So, as far as understand, binding does not work at all. Or I'm doing it wrong.
But maybe there is a way of solving it?

I'm running PHP 5.4.12 with PostgreSQL 9.2.3, libpq 8.4.16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it seems that the only solution is to cast all text values to text like this:

```
update test_table set test_field = :test_field::text
```

Otherwise error about inconsistent types is occurring.

Comment: Can you provide more information on how this is done in PHP and why it is needed?

Comment: I am curious about this feature, too. I had a similar binding problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236966/pdo-binding-fails-with-postgresql-window-function-parameters) and tried with both `:field::int` / `:field::integer` and `:field::text`, but it did not work. No reference on it in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
$stmt = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE test_field=:test_field");
$stmt->execute(array(":test_field" => 'test'));
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($result)
{
    return $result['id'];
    // Or whatever you're trying to get.
}
return null;
```

You just have to throw in an array of parameters in the execute function, no need to add a special line for the binding.

Tell me if it works for you (or not).

Comment: The problem is I'm getting error about inconsistent types when I'm trying to update table like this — set field_name = :field_name.