# PDO binding fails with PostgreSQL window function parameters

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, data-binding

I have to perform a SELECT query on a PostgreSQL database usign the `OVER()` [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html).

It allows to get either the range of selected rows specified through the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` values, or the number of total rows the query would get without the limit:

```
SELECT
     DISTINCT *, COUNT(id) OVER() AS results_num
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, surname
    FROM users
    WHERE children > 1
    ORDER BY id
) AS x
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

To develop a paging method I need to set *offset* and *limit* dynamically, so, using PDO, I define the query string setting placeholders for `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` variables which are then bound through [`bindParam()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT *, COUNT(id) OVER() AS results_num FROM (
    SELECT id, name, surname
    FROM users
    WHERE children > 1
    ORDER BY id
) AS x
OFFSET :offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :limit ROWS ONLY;"

$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$query->bindParam(':offset', $offset, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':limit', $limit, \PDO::PARAM_INT);

$result = $query->execute();
```

The error caught is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$2"
LINE 7:   ) AS x OFFSET $1 ROWS FETCH NEXT $2 ROWS ONLY;
                                            ^
```

The SQL error code is 42601 (`errorInfo` returns `SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7`), but it seems to be very generic, under this code I found a lot of different syntax errors.

It is not due to the named placeholders; infact the same happens by using question mark placeholders:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT *, COUNT(id) OVER() AS results_num FROM (
    SELECT id, name, surname
    FROM users
    WHERE children > 1
    ORDER BY id
) AS x
OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY;"

$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result = $query->execute([$offset, $limit]);
```

I know PDO also tries to validate the query structure, so is this type of syntax not allowed to be bound by PDO?

**EDIT:**

The query itself is well-formed and works; as far as now I use dynamic query string composition to set *offset* and *limit*, obviously after having properly validated their value:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT *, COUNT(id) OVER() AS results_num FROM (
    SELECT id, name, surname
    FROM users
    WHERE children > 1
    ORDER BY id
) AS x
OFFSET " . $offset . " ROWS FETCH NEXT " . $limit . " ROWS ONLY;"
```

Comment: Have you tried your statement as prepared statement directly in psql ?

Comment: @greg Yes, I tested it in several flavours and it works fine. As far as now I use it in production by setting the dynamic value of _offset_ and _limit_ through the concatenation of `$offset` and `$limit` variables in the query string.